# Is it possible to control the width of the SharePoint flyout form when using json to customize the form body?

Tags: json, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am using JSON to control the style of the edit form on my SharePoint list.  After defining the JSON, the width of the flyout panel expands to 90% of the screen.

**Is there any way to limit the width of the flyout panel?**

Basic SharePoint List
[image]

The default form width prior to JSON styling
[image]

Customizing the form layout using JSON
[image]

JSON-styled form expands to 90% of the screen
[image]

Header JSON:

```
{
"elmType": "div"
}
```

Body JSON:

```
{
"sections": [
    {
        "displayname": "",
        "fields": [
            "Identifier",
            "Title",
            "Workstream",
            "Type"
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "",
        "fields": [
            "AssignedTo",
            "AssignedAction"
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "",
        "fields": [
            "Comments"
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "",
        "fields": [
            "ReqDue",
            "ReqStatus",
            "DesignDue",
            "DesignStatus"
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "",
        "fields": [
            "DevDue",
            "DevStatus",
            "TestDue",
            "TestStatus"
        ]
    },
    {
        "displayname": "",
        "fields": [
            "eDataReqd"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: not possible to customize the form with PowerApps ?

Comment: I have a comments field in my list with "append changes" on... and PowerApps does not have a control available to render that content.  It can do a single comment, but it doesn't render the history of those previously appended as the default view does (very frustrating).